# Spfx breadcrumb not working on modern team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, react, modern-team-site

I am using the following breadcrum [sample](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-breadcrumb). I have deployed the latter to app catalog and it works fine in a developer site with modern pages/library but it doesn't work in a modern team site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,the element.xml file is the key. It is found in sharepoint-->assets-->element.xml

This means that the application will be deployed using feature configuration and **NEEDS TO BE ADDED TO EACH SITE MANUALLY HENCE WHEN ADDING THE PACKAGE TO APP CATALOG DO NOT CHECK THE BOX FOR DEPLOYMENT TO THE WHOLE TENANT**

Link to 
 [explanation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint)